# Get row index of second page of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have taken a GridView with paging having `pagesize=10` but when i move to second page & select 1st row of it then it shows the index as 11 despite 0 So please tell me how to resolve it.

Here is what i tried so far:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
      GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
      BindGrid();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     int index = (Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
     GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
     //Some operation 
}
```

When i try it for 11th row it throw error as:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

if i mannually pass the value to `index=0` it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say your datasoure returns 100 results. So a unique `DataItemIndex` will be assigned to your `CommandArgument` from 0 to 99.
Now if you have set `PageSize = 10` for your `gridview`, at a time only 10 rows will be visible. 
Say now you move to page 3 and click 3rd record the `DataItemIndex` will be 22 while your `GridView` has 10 rows visible and so index goes out of range.

```
int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) % GridView1.PageSize;
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowindex];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Convierte el numero almacenado en CommandArgument a int para sacar el index
// Converts the number stored in CommandArgument to int to remove the index
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

// Convierte el PageIndex del GridView a int
// Convert the PageIndex of the GridView to int
int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(gv_Comentarios.PageIndex);

// Convierte al index en la verdadera posicion del dataset
// It becomes the true position of the dataset to the index
if (pageIndex > 0)
{
    index = index + (pageIndex * 10);
}
```